# Get HTMLPrettify for sublimetext to add a tab before last closing bracket?

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm using [Sublime-HTMLPrettify](https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-HTMLPrettify#using-your-own-jsbeautifyrc-options)

But I like my code as

```
function my(way) {
    //code
    } // last bracket inline with the inside code
```

instead of the traditional

```
function default(way) {
    //code
} // last bracket inline with the function declaration
```

Because when folding it leaves the last bracket
[image]

Any way I can get the Prettify to add an extra tab like above before the last closing brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured out a hack, add spaces

```
output_lines[output_lines.length - 1].text.push('    ');
```

right before

```
print_token();
```

at [:1174](https://github.com/laggingreflex/Sublime-HTMLPrettify/blob/master/scripts/beautify.js#L1174) inside the `handle_end_block()` function.